# Dr Racket list function

Tags: scheme, racket

> Define a procedure `likenate` that takes a list and returns the list with the symbol `'like` inserted between each pair of adjacent elements in the given list.

I feel like this should be really easy, but I keep getting lists of lists so the check-expects aren't working. I've been stuck on this problem for over an hour. I've tried append and list* and some other things, but I can't figure out how to collapse a list of a list into one list or just get the function to work with the check-expects. Any help on this in BSL+ would be so great. Anyway, this is what I have:

```
; likenate : List -> List

(check-expect (likenate (list 'here 'be 'dragons)) 
              (list 'here 'like 'be 'like 'dragons))

(check-expect (likenate (list 'that 'is 'so 'cool)) 
              (list 'that 'like 'is 'like 'so 'like 'cool))

(check-expect (likenate (list 'like 'like)) 
              (list 'like 'like 'like))

(define (likenate list_like)
   (cond [(empty? list_like) '()]
   [else  (list (first list_like) 'like (likenate (rest list_like)))
  ]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, and you're on the right track thinking about `list*`. In fact, replacing `list` with `list*` in your attempt yields this program, which is almost exactly correct:

```
(define (likenate lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) '()]
        [else (list* (first lst) 'like (likenate (rest lst)))]))
```

You can think of `list*` as a shorthand for multiple `cons`es. To put it simply, `(list* a b c)` is equivalent to `(cons a (cons b c))`. This is necessary because the result of `likenate` is a *list*, so it needs to be the `cdr` element of the cons pair created by prepending the two new elements to this list.

That implementation *almost* works, with one small problem. It will insert `'like` elements at the end of the list, so you'll end up with lists like this, instead:

```
(list 'here 'like 'be 'like 'dragons 'like)
```

Just add an extra clause to the `cond` to handle the last element specially, and everything should work properly:

```
(define (likenate lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) '()]
        [(empty? (rest lst)) lst]
        [else (list* (first lst) 'like (likenate (rest lst)))]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version:

```
(define (likenate lst)
  (cond ((empty? (rest lst)) lst)
        (else (list* (first lst) 'like (likenate (rest lst))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using macros and `define-syntax`:

```
(define-syntax likenate
    (syntax-rules () 
      [(_ ()) '()]      
      [(_ (e1 e2 ...)) (cons e1 (cons 'like (likenate (e2 ...))))]))
```

One difference is that when calling this function, you don't need to call the `list` function:

`(likenate ('here 'be 'dragons))` => `(here like be like dragons like)`